# Best way to store long list of coordinates?

Tags: android, coordinates

I have a map in my application that needs to be searchable by building and to also have two sets of icon overlays (to show where certain things are). I have the longitude and latitude of the 100+ points of interest and I'm wondering: what is the best way to store and access them? I need each data point to include a name (String) and two float values. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Two options: one is to use `SharedPreferences.Editor` to `putFloat` and just use whatever name you had in mind as the key for the preferences entry. But, you might find it awkward to use preferences to store 100+ pieces of data, so you might want to use SQLite..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100+ records is enough to justify using a SQLite database.   That is what i'd do.